# Dell R710 RAM Upgrade - Making sure I get this right

Tags: memory, dell, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell R710 that's refurbished (so no warranty or support by Dell) and currently has 48 GB of RAM in it (12x4GB). According to the `smbiosDump` in ESXi, it looks like this:

```
# smbiosDump | egrep '(Number:|Location)'
    Location: "DIMM_A1"
    Part Number: "36JSZF51272PZ1G4F1"
    Location: "DIMM_A2"
    Part Number: "36JSZF51272PZ1G4F1"
    Location: "DIMM_A3"
    Part Number: "HMT151R7BFR4C-H9"
    Location: "DIMM_A4"
    Part Number: "36JSZF51272PZ1G4F1"
    Location: "DIMM_A5"
    Part Number: "36JSZF51272PZ1G4F1"
    Location: "DIMM_A6"
    Part Number: "M393B5170EH1-CH9"
    Location: "DIMM_A7"
    Location: "DIMM_A8"
    Location: "DIMM_A9"
    Location: "DIMM_B1"
    Part Number: "36JSZF51272PZ1G4F1"
    Location: "DIMM_B2"
    Part Number: "36JSZF51272PZ1G4F1"
    Location: "DIMM_B3"
    Part Number: "HMT151R7BFR4C-H9"
    Location: "DIMM_B4"
    Part Number: "36JSZF51272PZ1G4F1"
    Location: "DIMM_B5"
    Part Number: "36JSZF51272PZ1G4F1"
    Location: "DIMM_B6"
    Part Number: "M393B5170EH1-CH9"
    Location: "DIMM_B7"
    Location: "DIMM_B8"
    Location: "DIMM_B9"
```

As you can see, I have 6 open slots on the board so an entire channel is free for use. I'm currently using the "Optimized" mode, which according to the manual means I can fill this third channel with additional RAM.

I noticed that there's 3 different part numbers for the RAM on this server. These two (M393B5170EH1-CH9 and HMT151R7BFR4C-H9) appear to by [Hynix](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HSQP8QU) RAM which is compatible. The third one is an unknown Samsung that I can't find anywhere.

So, my question is this: If I were to purchase additional RAM (the Hynix one linked above), is it safe to say that this will work? The manual for compatibility is confusing, so I want to get this right. I had purchased Corsair RAM (8 GB, 4xr8, 1333Mhz, ECC) but the server rejected it when I installed them, so I'd like to avoid repeating my mistake!

Comment: Have you contacted Dell?

Comment: No. I'd rather avoid it since I'd probably only get advice to purchase Dell RAM which, as I'm sure you know, is far overpriced compared to other vendors.

Comment: I'd still question Dell and if they ask say you have dell memory.  Afterall you are only asking for configuration information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would search on the [official Dell part number](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&q=SNPX3R5MC%2F8G&oq=SNPX3R5MC%2F8G&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.11249.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.ecynfh...0...1..55.serp..0.0.0.RYS36Mvp76s). It's not about the OEM for RAM like this. It's about the compatible part numbers (from Dell's perspective).

Buy [SNPX3R5MC/8G](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2060778.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.XSNPX3R5MC%2F8G%20&_nkw=SNPX3R5MC%2F8G%20&_sacat=0).

Answer (score 1):

This question is on the borderline of shopping, but I can tell you our experience with those servers.

Dell, like any other server vendor, wants your unborn children for upgrades after you've bought a server. My solution was to replace all the RAM in the system with Kingston system-specific memory, which have a lifetime guarantee and is 100% compatible.

Note that it will probably void any kind of support agreement you have, so I would keep the old RAM sticks around and install them if you ever need a onsite support engineer from Dell.

A word of caution: Triple-channel is not recommended on these servers, as it will lower your bus speed. Using quad rank modules makes it even worse (down from 1333mhz to 800mhz). This has a rather substantial impact on environments where there is a large amount of memory usage (virtualization, databases etc). I would go for 16GB Dual Rank modules, which should give you a nice upgrade to 192GB with 2 CPU's installed.